# Did Neil Marshall deliberately reference The Matrix in Dog Soldiers?

Tags: reference, the-matrix, dog-soldiers

In the film *Dog Soldiers* by Neil Marshall, the following dialogue occurs between two characters:

> Where is Spoon?
>
> There is no Spoon

The Spoon referenced in the dialogue was one of the characters in the film who was eaten by werewolves.

Was this a deliberate reference to *The Matrix*?

Comment: Of course it is. The film contains many references to other movies. The Searchers chief among them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia page for the movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_Soldiers_%28film%29), the director, cast and crew commentary on the DVD confirms that:

> The film contains homages to H.G. Wells, the films The Evil Dead,
>   Zulu, Aliens, The Matrix and Star Trek: The Wrath of Khan.

That means that the dialogue mention by you is directly referring to The Matrix.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, only provides a list of other movie references within the movie.

Comment: @TylerShads he asked `was this a deliberate reference to the Matrix film with Neo and Morpheus?` then lines from wiki clearifying it by yes.

Comment: I think what TylerShads is getting at is: there's no confirmation that these EXACT lines were definitely, YES, THE reference to The Matrix, merely that the commentary confirms there ARE references. Given the similarities and confirmation of references, I tend to think that the question is answered satisfactorily, but there might still be more references to the Matrix contained within. Finding others COULD make these exact lines a happy coincidence.

Comment: The lines were not a happy coincidence. To learn the movie referenced another movie, and then *accidentally* referencing *probably the most famous line* from the movie is **highly unlikely**. Extremely, extremely improbable.